# istio failover in the same cluster cross different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, istio, failover

we can do istio multicluster failover using outlier detection with shared control plane with https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/shared/, so we have the exactly same service running in two clusters, if one fails, it will switch to the healthy automatically, that works perfectly.
recently, we have a new request which is to do the same failover in the same cluster cross namespaces with the same service. such as my-service.ns1 and my-service.ns2, from the doc we can do traffic shifting with below code, not sure if there's way to do the failover, thanks.

```
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: helloworld
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - helloworld-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /hello
    route:
    - destination:
        host: helloworld.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: helloworld.test.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 5000
      weight: 50
```